# Let $X=\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ distribution. And $Y=\lambda X$. Find the density of $Y$

Tags: statistics

So I have that $F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}=P(X\leq x)$, for $x\geq 0$

Then $F_Y(x)=P(Y\leq x)=P(\lambda X\leq x)=P(X\leq \frac{x}{\lambda})=1-e^{-x}$

For $x\geq 0$

I'm just not sure if this works because $\lambda$ could be negative?

In that case I would have $P(Y\leq x)=e^{-x}$?

Comment: $\lambda $ is defined positive.

Comment: It is $f_Y(x)=e^{-x} \ \  \forall \ x>0$ rather than $P(Y\leq x)=e^{-x}$ Please give a reply if you have noticed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct and $\lambda$ can't be negative, since we need $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)=1$, we must have that $e^{-\lambda x}\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$, hence we should have that $\lambda x\to\infty$ if $x\to\infty$, so $\lambda>0$